# Prevent data bind for child component in ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a component that is using child component inside ngFor loop. This child component has a data binding that is read with `@Input`.

The problem I'm facing is that when I push data to Child Component, each instance of child component gets the same value.
Is there any way to push data only for a specific instance of child component bind in ngFor?

[Here is a dummy example I created](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfgydr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I want it to work in that way when I click the first button, only the first child component should get value but second, should be empty.

I'm new in angular environment so any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

`pushToChild` would be shared across the children so let's not use it. The simplest way I can think of is passing the values directly to the children using a child DOM element converted to a variable declaration (`#child`) which is unique when looping thru.

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child-component/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  object: { [key: number]: string } = { 2: 'foo', 1: 'bar' };

  push(value: any, child: ChildComponent) {
    child.data = value;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<span>
  <p>Some dummy list</p>
  <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue"
       style="background:gray; margin-top:0.5rem">
    Click button to push value: {{ item.key }} to child
    <button (click)="push(item.key, childRef)">Push</button>
    <child-component #childRef></child-component>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: You could get rid of the `push` method: `(click)="child.data = item.key"`.